# C# PowerBi Dataset Refresh notifyOption

Tags: c#, powerbi

Is it possible to schedule a powerbi dataset refresh with c# and receive a notification after the completion?

According to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/refresh-dataset) if SP is used (as i already do) the option to receive the completition email is not applicable. I'm forced to pass "NoNotification" in the body of the refresh request post. Which others ways are available to refresh the dataset with C# that can also allow the user to receive a confirmation email?

Comment: Refreshing a dataset and sending a notification email can be discreet, decoupled operations. Both can be achieved using C# or something a lot easier like PowerAutomate/LogicApps.

Comment: We've generally used powerAutomate/azuredatafactory for triggering refresh and notifications.